# List all elements of the relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

The task is to List all elements of the relations (d)   S`, S-1 and S ₀T.

```
S ⊆{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} x {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
S = {〈1, 1〉, 〈1, 3〉, 〈1, 5〉, 〈2, 2〉, 〈2, 4〉, 〈3, 1〉, 〈3, 3〉, 〈5, 3〉}
```

My solution is:

```
S-1 = {〈1,1〉, 〈3,1〉, 〈5,1〉, 〈2,2〉, 〈4,2〉, 〈1,3〉, 〈3,3〉, 〈3,5〉}

S ₀T = {〈1,3〉, 〈1,5〉, 〈1,1〉, 〈2,4〉, 〈3,1〉, 〈3,3〉, 〈3,5〉, 〈5,1〉}
```

But I did not get the idea how to do S`. Can please somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Let $U = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} \times \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$.

> $S-1 = \{\langle b, a \rangle \in U: \langle a, b \rangle \in S\}$,
>
> $S \circ T = \{\langle a, c\rangle \in S ~~|~~ \exists b: \langle a,b \rangle \in T\land \langle b,c \rangle \in S\}$,
>
> $S' = \{\langle a,b \rangle \in U : \langle a,b \rangle \not\in S\}$.

The task is to calculate 1. ($S-1$), 2. ($S \circ \top$), and 3. ($S'$) for the following set:

> $S = \{〈1, 1〉, 〈1, 3〉, 〈1, 5〉, 〈2, 2〉, 〈2, 4〉, 〈3, 1〉, 〈3, 3〉, 〈5, 3〉\}$

1. $(S-1) = \{\langle b, a \rangle \in S: \langle a, b \rangle \in S\}$ $= \{\langle 1,1\rangle, \langle 3,1\rangle, \langle 5,1\rangle, \langle 2,2\rangle, \langle 4,2\rangle, \langle 1,3\rangle, \langle 3,3\rangle, \langle 3,5\rangle\} ~{\color{green}\checkmark}$
2. $(S\circ \top) = \{\langle a, c\rangle \in S ~~|~~ \exists b: \langle a,b \rangle \in T\land \langle b,c \rangle \in S\}$
   $= \{\langle 1,1\rangle, \langle 1,3\rangle, \langle 1,5\rangle, \langle 2,2\rangle, \langle 3,1\rangle, \langle 3,3\rangle, \langle 5,3\rangle\}$.
3. $S'$ = (*see the first comment below*).

Comment: Needless to say: $S' = \{\langle 1,2\rangle, \langle 1,4\rangle, \ldots, \langle 5,5\rangle\}$. Just calculate.

Comment: And the rest of the task is right?

Comment: That depends on your definitions of $S-1$ and $S_o\top$. How are they defined?

Comment: S-1 = {〈b,a〉 | 〈a,b〉 ∈S}

Comment: S ₀ T= {〈a,c〉| there is a b ∈B: aTb and bSc}

Comment: Are those relative to $U$ or $S$? For example, is $S-1$ equal to $\{\langle b, a\rangle \in S : \langle a, b\rangle\in S\}$ or $\{\langle b, a\rangle \in U : \langle a, b\rangle\in S\}$?

Comment: i guess it refers to S

Comment: Your answer is correct with $U$ for the first one. For the circle one, which set is $B$? $U$ or $S$?

Comment: when it stays that T ⊆ N x N; 〈x, y〉∈ T if x is a factor of y, i.e. y can be divided by x without remainder. For instance, 〈3, 12〉∈ T, but 〈5, 12〉 ∉ T, does that mean that S ₀T = {〈1,3〉, 〈1,5〉, 〈1,1〉, 〈2,4〉, 〈3,3〉}

Comment: See the updated answer.